# Не запускается sqlplus через external jobs

Tags: oracle, centos, plsql, oracle11g

Ошибка банальная:

> ```
> ORA-27369: job of type EXECUTABLE failed with exit code: Operation not permitted
> STANDARD_ERROR="Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus
> SP2-0667: Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found
> SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory"
> ```

В externaljob.ora прописан юзер oracle с группой oinstall.
В .bash_profile юзера oracle прописаны все перменные:

```
[oracle@testdb ~]$ set | grep ORACLE
ORACLE_BASE=/ora/app/oracle
ORACLE_HOME=/ora/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1
ORACLE_HOSTNAME=testdb
ORACLE_SID=ORCL
ORACLE_UNQNAME=ORCL
```

Сделал примитивный bash-скрипт с редиректом текущих системных переменных в отдельный текстовый файл. Если запустить из консоли, то все переменные на месте. 
При запуске через external job юзер остается oracle, но нет переменных.

Как решить проблему?

Comment: А вы уверены что оракл запускает bash ? Что то мне подсказывает, что он сходу стартует указанный выполнимый файл, без участия программы-оболочки. Тогда возможно стоит явно выполнять баш с параметрами которые запустят внешний скрипт который в свою очередь уже запустит sqlplus

Comment: @Mike Примерно такой воркэраунд я сейчас и сделал. Заменил sqlplus на софтлинк скрипта, который устанавливает переменные и запускает уже настоящий sqlplus. Такой костыль не хочется оставлять, хочется красивого решения.

Comment: Запуск внешнего sqlplus это уже странно. почему бы не выполнять требуемые sql-запросы непосредственно.

Comment: @Mike раз в n-дней нужно накатывать n-количество sql файлов сгенерированных на другой стороне.

Comment: Зачем задачу планировать через оракл, а не воспользоваться стандартными средствами - т.е. cron. Правда там с переменными окружения все равно будут некоторые проблемы. Окружение в таком случае желательно сформировать глобально, что бы оно уже было на момент старта самого оракла или крона (см. /etc/env.d, хотя я не уверен что на вашем дистрибудтиве оно именно там)

Comment: @Mike таких баз, реципиентов, 700+ на разных ОС

Comment: А у вас все равно без вариантов. sqlplus нужны переменные окружения. при запуске его самого никакие .bash_profile выполнятся не будут. так что внешние скрипты. Или ищите как установить окружение средствами заданий оракла

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle вызывает *executuble*, указанный в *external job*. напрямую, т.е. без оболочки и в пустом окружении. 
Из [комментария топикастера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/558541/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-sqlplus-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-external-jobs-linux-oracle11-2-0-4/562665#comment724350_558541):

> Заменил sqlplus на софтлинк скрипта, который устанавливает переменные и запускает уже настоящий sqlplus. Такой костыль не хочется оставлять, хочется красивого решения.

Это собственно и есть правильное решение.

---

Или можно создать универсальную задачу запускающую оболочку с чтением логин скриптов, а затем в ней запускать желаемую программу (или даже built-in, function и т.д.):

```
begin
    dbms_scheduler.create_job (
        job_name => '"SH1"."shell_exec"',
        job_type => 'EXECUTABLE',
        job_action => '/bin/bash',
        number_of_arguments => 2,
        start_date => to_date('2099','yyyy'),
        repeat_interval => NULL,
        end_date => NULL,
        enabled => false,
        auto_drop => false,
        comments => 'execute some command in bash');

    dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value( 
         job_name => '"SH1"."shell_exec"', 
         argument_position => 1, 
         argument_value => '-lc');    
    dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value( 
         job_name => '"SH1"."shell_exec"', 
         argument_position => 2, 
         argument_value => 'env > ~/env.out; echo "env ok" >/dev/stderr; exit 0');
    dbms_scheduler.enable('"SH1"."shell_exec"');
end;
/

exec sys.dbms_scheduler.run_job('"SH1"."shell_exec"');
```

В ~/env.out вывод полного окружение пользователя в режиме не интерактивного логина.
Ещё один пример запуска и просмотр вывода на стандртный поток ошибок:

```
begin 
    dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value( 
         job_name => '"SH1"."shell_exec"', 
         argument_position => 2, 
         argument_value => 'echo "try some command here" >/dev/stderr ; exit 0');
         dbms_scheduler.run_job('"SH1"."shell_exec"');
end;
/
select additional_info from dba_scheduler_job_run_details where job_name = 'shell_exec';
ADDITIONAL_INFO
STANDARD_ERROR="env ok"    
STANDARD_ERROR="try some command here"
```

В главе [28.3.1.2.1 About External Jobs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schedover004.htm#BGBDCCCE), кроме всего прочего, описано, как установить пользователя и группу, с которыми будет запущена задача.