# Получить имена всех файлов в папке на PL/SQL (Oracle XE)

Tags: java, .net, oracle, plsql

Есть папка (локально) С:\LB в которую некто закидывает файлы. Мне необходимо (периодически, через определенное время) получать имена всех этих файлов, и если в этих именах есть то имя, которое мне надо, я цепляю этот файл (.PDF) к определенной записи в таблице.

Пока я работаю над получением списка имен файлов:

```
create global temporary table DIR_LIST (filename varchar2(255)) 
on commit delete rows;
/

create or replace and compile java source named "DirList" as 
import java.io.*; 
import java.sql.*; 

public class DirList 
{ 
    public static void getList(String directory) throws SQLException 
    { 
        File path = new File( directory ); 
        String[] list = path.list(); 
        String element; 

        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) 
        { 
            element = list[i]; 
            #sql { INSERT INTO DIR_LIST (FILENAME) VALUES (:element) }; 
        } 
    } 
} 
/

create or replace procedure get_dir_list( p_directory in varchar2 ) 
as language java 
name 'DirList.getList( java.lang.String )';
```

БД 11g XE и я не могу развернуть JAVA внутри. Писать внешний JAR-ник не совсем актуально. Я так понимаю нужен шедулер и JOB, но все форумы говорят что на чистом PL/SQL этого (получить имена файлов и превратить их в таблицу) написать нельзя. Ок. Возможно можно развернуть .NET классы внутри БД, обернув в процедуру? Как с классами JAVA. Уверен, кто-то определенно с этим сталкивался. Буду благодарен за подсказки!

Comment: Какие проблемы с java? Вроде самый простой способ. Вы правда не с java пробуете,  а с sqlj. Можно также на plsql  или не c.

Comment: Какие проблемы с java? Не поддерживает XE sqlj. Внешний джарник-долго. Клиент будет не очень доволен. По тз нужно на PL SQL или sqlj. Вроде уже нашел решение. Но думаю может есть у кого-то еще варианты.
Java support in the database

No

Java Server Pages

No

Java native compilation

No

SQLJ

No

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/license.112/e18068/toc.htm#XELIC117

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно с помощью внешних таблиц реализовать:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/stage

$ cat >/tmp/stage/readdir.sh<<eof
#/bin/bash
cd /tmp/stage/
/bin/ls -1
eof

$ for i in {1..5}; do touch /tmp/stage/invoice_no_$RANDOM.pdf; done
```

В SQL*Plus:

```
create or replace directory stagedir as '/tmp/stage'
/
Directory STAGEDIR created.

create table files (filename varchar2(255))
organization external ( 
    type oracle_loader
    default directory stagedir
    access parameters (
        records delimited by newline
        preprocessor  stagedir:'readdir.sh'
        fields terminated by "|" ldrtrim
    )
location ('readdir.sh')
)
/
Table FILES created.

select * from files;

FILENAME                                                                       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FILES_27463.log                                                                 
invoice_no_20891.pdf                                                            
invoice_no_2255.pdf                                                             
invoice_no_24086.pdf                                                            
invoice_no_30372.pdf                                                            
invoice_no_8340.pdf                                                             
readdir.sh                                                                      

 7 rows selected
```

Можно также с [разовым job](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/558541/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-sqlplus-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-external-jobs-linux-oracle11-2-0-4/562665#562665), но это решение будет явно потяжелей, т.к. стандртный вывод нельзя напрямую вернуть в вызывающую процедуру. Зато, как клиент пожелал, всё будет реализовано на PL/SQL.

---

Автор вопроса [@TehD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/592200/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-pl-sql-oracle-xe/592966#comment798832_592966) опробовал решение на Windows, цитирую:

> **Комментарий для Windows:**
> Если у Вас, (как и у меня) в работе Windows Server 2008,
> то в директорию с файлами, кладем .bat с кодом:
>
> ```
>  @echo off dir /b "путь к папке без кавычек"
> ```
>
> для настроек возврата из .bat смотрим `dir /?`
> Ну и меняем конечно readdir.sh на readdir.bat

Comment: "стандртный вывод нельзя на прямую вернуть в вызывающую процедуру" - не совсем понимаю о чем Вы, можно пояснение или ссылку?

Comment: Если использовать 'ls, dir' и им подобные, как в примере выше, их  'stdout'  надо както вернуть или считать, например: перенаправить в файл и считать его содержимое тем же 'utl_file'. 'job' подсоединяется только к 'stderr', и то его обрезает.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение.

Comment: **Комментарий для Windows:** Если у Вас, (как и у меня) в работе Windows Server 2008, то в директорию с файлами, кладем .bat с кодом:
 `@echo off
dir /b "путь к папке без кавычек"`
для настроек возврата из .bat смотрим `dir /?`

Comment: Ну и меняем конечно readdir.sh на readdir.bat