# Заполнение таблицы с полем CLOB из текстовых файлов

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, clob

В определённой папке лежат текстовые файлы с именами, например, `file_<номер>.json`. Нужно из всех файлов в папке считать текст и заполнить им столбец таблицы типа CLOB, каждый файл в новой строке.

Не могу разобраться как работать с файловой системой.

Пока нашёл такое [решение](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/load-lob-data-using-sql-loader). Но, список файлов нужно самому писать.

Comment: возможно задачу иммет смысл решать не средствами оракла?

Comment: @Viktorov, боюсь, других средств у нас нет. А почему нельзя? Ведь можно загрузить данные из файла. В БД же грузим.

Comment: Добавте пример данных.  В вопросе упомяното три формата:  sql, txt, json.

Comment: Можно решить 2 способами. 1(силами оракла). Объявить внутри оракла директорию и через пакеты(например UTL_FILE) грузить файлы и вставлять в таблицу. 2 взять какой нибудь ЯП(например java) и относительно быстро написать скрипт загрузки содержимого файлов в БД

Comment: @Viktorov беда в том, что я не умею в java (хотя на C# работал). О директории - это вы про использование внешних таблиц говорите?

Comment: @0xdb формат не суть важен, можно просто из txt грузить всё содержимое в одну ячейку CLOB.

Comment: почитайте про UTL_FILE, например на русском http://my-oracle.it-blogs.com.ua/post-66.aspx

Comment: Я посмотрел, там и на C# подключиться к ораклу - пара строчек. Еще несколько на обработку файлов и вставку в таблицу. Выглядит довольно несложно. Правда не знаю, что там про загрузку именно clob

Comment: Вот так сделал: https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/load-lob-data-using-sql-loader
Правда, список файлов нужно самому писать (может можно через батник будет заполнить список файлов к загрузке, но это уж е не критично)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Один из способов без *SQL*Loader*. Какой способ предпочтительней можно решить только исходя из требований конкретной задачи (сколько файлов, размер, частота обновлений, необходимость обработки ошибок и т.д.).

Создал файл `/tmp/file1.json` с примером JSON данных и далее:

```
create or replace directory jsonFiles as '/tmp';

create table jsonData (id int primary key, json clob);

create or replace procedure loadJsonFromFile (id number, fileName varchar2) as 
    myJson clob; 
    myFile bfile; 
    srcOffset int := 1;
    destOffset int := 1;
    langContext int := dbms_lob.default_lang_ctx; 
    warn int;
begin 
    insert into jsonData values (id, empty_clob()) 
    returning json into myJson
    ; 
    myFile := bfilename (upper ('jsonFiles'), fileName); 
    dbms_lob.fileopen (myFile); 
    dbms_lob.loadClobFromFile (
        myJson, myFile, dbms_lob.getLength (myFile), 
        srcOffset, destOffset, 0, langContext, warn); 
    dbms_lob.fileclose (myFile);
end; 
/ 

exec loadJsonFromFile (1, 'file1.json');

select id, dbms_lob.substr (json, 80) json from jsonData;

        ID JSON
---------- -------------------------------------------------
         1 {"menu": {
             "id": "file",
             "value": "File",
             "popup": {
               "menuitem": [
```

Подробнее [в оф. документации](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_lob.htm#i998978).

Практически любой проект имеет готовое решение для считывания содержимого директории. Если нет, то список файлов к загрузке можно получить как описано, например, [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/592200/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-pl-sql-oracle-xe/592966#592966).