# Как скопировать/прочитать файл с удалённого сервера?

Tags: sql, файлы, oracle, plsql

У меня есть сервер с приложением и сервер БД. Приложение размещает на своём сервере файл. Нужно его прочитать с сервера БД.

Из того, что нашёл это `DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER.GET_FILE`, но чтобы взять файл с удалённого сервера, на нём должна быть установленна БД.

Или с помощью `DBMS_SCHEDULER` выполнить команду `cmd`, чтобы скопировать файл с удалённого сервера, но это решение, мне кажется, не очень.

Comment: *но это мне кажется не очень* Скорее архитектура у Вас "не очень". Если файл нужен на сервере БД - туда его (либо его копию) и следует класть. Собственно это можно поручить и серверу приложения - по событию размещения на нём файла, например...

Comment: я понимаю, но я бдшник, могу только pl sql написать)

Comment: Если файл текстовый, попробуйте использовать [UTL_FILE package](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_file.htm). А если он ещё и может взять файл по его UNC, так вообще всё шоколадно...

Comment: по unc он не может, но спасибо за это, я не знал раньше про него))

Comment: Напишите скрипт, который будет регулярно (или по событию) копировать файлы на сервер БД, а там их читайте. В чём проблема? Почему вы иммено в на стороне самой БД ищете способ получить файлы с удалённого сервера?

Comment: это понятно, это крайняя мера, если ничего не получится, придётся так. Я именно про бд спросил, есть ли другие варианты

Comment: Почему это крайняя мера, так все делают. Если соображения безопасности позволяют, то создайте сетевой каталог и в БД директорию на него, и читайте оттуда. Вроде `create directory ...` даже UNC поддерживает (я не пробовал).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как один из вариантов решения:

- сделать каталог с файлами на сервере приложений общим
- смонтировать его на сервере БД
- создать объект директории и читать оттуда файлы в PL/SQL блоке

Например, смонтировал сетевой каталог `//wincomputer/appshare` под `/mnt/share/`, и далее:

```
create directory appshare as '/mnt/share'
/
Directory APPSHARE created.
```

Для чтения списка файлов [воспользовался этим решением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/592966), заменив имена таблицы и каталога на `appfiles` и `appshare` соответственно. Создал новый файл на Windows машине:

```
D:\> echo abc123 >appshare\appfile_123.txt
```

, и прочёл его на сервере БД:

```
SQL> col filename new_value filename
SQL> select *
     from appfiles where filename like 'appfile%';

FILENAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
appfile_123.txt

set autoprint 
var rc refcursor
declare
    f utl_file.file_type;
    buff varchar2 (128);
begin
    f := utl_file.fopen (upper ('appshare'), '&filename', 'r');
    utl_file.get_line (f, buff);
    utl_file.fclose (f); 
    open :rc for 
        select '&filename'||' contains >>'||buff||'<<' result from dual;
end;
/
```

Результат:

```
RESULT
-----------------------------------
appfile_123.txt contains >>abc123 
<<
```

Comment: да, я так и сделал, спросил у тимлида как лучше сделать, он сказал сделаю общую папку)) но за ответ спасибо)